# Disable a wiki in Lion Server?

Tags: mac-osx-server, wiki, osx-lion

Any way to disable a wiki in Lion Server's Wiki Server?

It's easy enough to *delete* one but how to temporarily **disable** one so it can be resurrected later?

Comment: <crickets> no one has any suggestions? </crickets>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing the access permissions on it so only the owner can access it? Then it shouldn't be visible to anyone but them.